# VS2019 Xamarin Forms Remote IOS simulator Black screen - How to fix?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms Project
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9
Xcode on Mac version 12.4
Using IPad Pro 11 inch running 14.4 as the simulated device and IOS version.
( I tried other simulators )

If I build and run Simulation on the Mac, it works. So i believe it is a remote simulation issue.

[image: Use remote simulation on Windows]
If you set IOS simulator to remote it starts and appears to run the simulation
in the simulator but it just shows a black screen.
Ive updated everything I can think of. Mac OS, XCODE on latest available.
Visual Studio, W10, all latest available and everything restarted...
Still it doesnt work. You do see brief at time of deployment dots spinner that reminds of the spinner when shutting down.
How do I fix the back screen simulation. ?

EDIT: With Latest Updates, it works again.
After upgrading to VS2022, upgrading Xcode on the mac.
Even the simulators are now ios15.x
Somewhere is all those updates the problem is gone.

[image]

Comment: One way I tried was to start the simulator on mac first and then run the project from VS.

Comment: Hi @Shaw,  I tried that, still black locally(remote simulation)  but runs fine when the simulation runs on the mac.  From Home I can use VNC viewer to see it running on the MAC.  Starting the simulator first didnt help remote simulation.
Looks just like some bug in VS2019 was introduced with 16.8.x  
I havent tried 16.9 preview yet

Comment: I encountered this issue from time to time but got no definite solution, ie. sometimes server error, sometimes black, sometimes both two simulators run perfectly and synchronously, sometimes needs to update mac as you mentioned, or clean bin&obj. And eventually, I turned to test on iPhone (remote).

Comment: There's an odd situation, that I encountered a long time ago, where if you've run simulator on Mac first, the "state" of the remote flag seems to get confused, when you then try to remote. Stop the remote debugger on pc. Fully exit the simulator on mac, using the menu. So it doesn't start again when you restart the mac. Restart mac and pc. Try again from pc (WITHOUT running simulator first on mac). If that doesn't work: toggle the option on the pc, so that it shows on the mac instead. Run everything, see that working. NOW, toggle back on, and do all the steps above again.

Answer (score 0):

- You could have a try with **Forget the Device** first:

[image]

- Next step, better need to reboot Mac .
- Last, Pair to Mac again with **Add Mac** manually:

[image]

If it also can not work, maybe need to check the quality of network whether is well.

Comment: its not the "quality" of the network, Ill check the firewall log.  But that would surprise me.
Thanks for trying, but still a black simulator

Comment: @philsoady Okey, it's strange. You could have a try with other simulators or physical devices to check whether it can run successfully first.

Comment: On the Mac the simulators are running fine as are real devices. Currently I'm using vnc to look at and test the app on the Mac.. Ok for me but not other colleagues.

Comment: @philsoady If so, you could submit it as an issue in Visual Studio.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/feedback-options?view=vs-2019