# Remote debugging of iOS app on windows doesn't work. When running simulator on PC just showing black screen

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin

I have Xamarin forms app for android and iOS.

When I try to debug iOS on my PC in Visual Studio 2019, the simulator just showing me a black screen. All controls in the simulator are disabled.

If I uncheck Remote Simulator to Windows (Tools->Options->Xamarin->iOS Settings), then I can see my app running fine on my Mac (M1). On Mac, I have Visual Studio 2019.

I had a Macincloud account last month and everything worked great, but switching to a real Mac (M1) doesn't go well.

Did somebody experience the same problem? I spent already few hours trying to debug iOS on PC, but so far no luck.
I tried this:

- [VS2019 Xamarin Forms Remote IOS simulator Black screen - How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374796/vs2019-xamarin-forms-remote-ios-simulator-black-screen-how-to-fix;)
- uninstalling/installing xCode 12
- changing default folder for xCode

Thank you!

Comment: Well I had the same problem and gave up on it - but I tested it again on VS 16.11.2 and now it's working for me

Comment: yep, the same for me now. Yeah! Now I can develop iOS and Android on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Remote Simulator to Windows.
Quit Simulator on Mac and run again.